# impossible to retrieve Paypal information after successful payment

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal payment on a sales site. the client part works well, the client pays and the money is in the seller account. the second part which allows to recover data such as transaction number, amount, customer address, does not work. yet I use the scripts provided by Paypal.

**this file index.php to pay works**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Radiofil</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary mb-1">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Boutique Tubes</a>


    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>Récapitulatif</h1>

      <table class="table table-striped">
     
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Tube</th>
          <th>Qte</th>
          <th>Prix</th>
       
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

         <?php 
          $user_id = 8000;
       $RefBonCommande= '20000';
     include('../config/dbconn.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM detailcde WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND RefBonCommande='$RefBonCommande'") or die (mysqli_error());

     while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM)) {


    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
     
    $numerotube=$row3[3];
    $qty= $row3[4];
    $totalp = $row3[5];

          echo "<tr>";
          echo  "<td>".$numerotube."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$qty."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$totalp.'€'."</td>";
    }
     $query1 = mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM commandes WHERE Refcde='$RefBonCommande' AND adherent1='$user_id'") or die (mysqli_error()); 
     $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
     $port=$row4['FraisTransport'];
     $total=$row4['Total'];
       echo "<tr>";
          echo  "<td>".'Total + port '."</td>";
       echo "<td>".'1 '."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$total.'€'."</td>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><b><font size = 5>".'Commande de l\'adherent RFL n° '.$user_id."</b></br></td>"; 
    ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <!--<p class="text-right">
        <div id="paypal-button"></div>
        <!--<a href="payment.php" class="btn btn-success">Acheter</a>-->
      </p>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

      <script
        src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client-id&currency=EUR"> // Required. Replace SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID.

        paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');

        // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
     </script>
    <center> 
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div> 
      </center>
      <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: <?php echo $total ;?>  //'5.60'
              }
            }]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by adherent ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            // Call your server to save the transaction
            return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                orderID: data.orderID,
       payerID: data.payerID
       })
       
            });
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');

      </script>

    </body>
    </html>




**the script below does not work**



<!-- language: lang-PHP -->

    <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    ?>

    <script>
    // 1. Set up your server to make calls to PayPal

    // 1a. Add your client ID and secret
    PAYPAL_CLIENT = cliet id';
    PAYPAL_SECRET = secret';

    // 1b. Point your server to the PayPal API
    PAYPAL_OAUTH_API = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/';
    PAYPAL_ORDER_API = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/';

    // 1c. Get an access token from the PayPal API
    basicAuth = base64encode(`${ PAYPAL_CLIENT }:${ PAYPAL_SECRET }`);
    auth = http.post(PAYPAL_OAUTH_API ,{
      headers: {
        Accept:        `application/json`,
        Authorization: `Basic ${ basicAuth }`
      },
      data: `grant_type=client_credentials`
    });

    // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    function handleRequest(request, response), {

      // 2a. Get the order ID from the request body
      orderID = request.body.orderID;

      // 3. Call PayPal to capture the order
      capture = http.post(PAYPAL_ORDER_API + orderID + '/capture', {
        headers: {
          Accept:        `application/json`,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${ auth.access_token }`
        }
      });

      // 4. Save the capture ID to your database
      if (!capture.error) {
        captureID = capture.purchase_units[0]
            .payments.captures[0].id;
        database.saveCaptureID(captureID);
      }

      // 5. Handle any errors from the call
      if (capture.error) {
        console.error(capture.error);
        return response.send(500);
      }

      // 6. Return a successful response to the client
      response.send(200);
    }




hello, according to the advice of PHPology I set up the return call URL and of course used the PAYPAL script. I went to the history of IPN messages and I have an HTTP 500 error. I think there may be a syntax error in the PAYPAL script they are specialists in this kind of error.

     <?php
    function ipn($ipn_data) {

    define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
        $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            //You can send email as well
        }
        return false;
    }

    // parse the paypal URL
    $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
    $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

    $post_string = '';
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
        $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
    // get the correct paypal url to post request to
    $paypal_mode_status = $ipn_data; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
    if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
    else
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);

    $ipn_response = '';

    if (!$fp) {
        // could not open the connection. If loggin is on, the error message
        // will be in the log.
        $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'fsockopen fail';
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        // Post the data back to paypal
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }
    // Invalid IPN transaction. Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
    if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
        $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'Validation fail';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
        if ($ipn_data == true) {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

function ipn_response() {
    //mail("sobhagya1411@gmail.com","My subject",print_r($request,true));
    $ipn_data = true;
    if ($this->ipn($_REQUEST)) {
        $this->insert_data($_REQUEST);
    }
}

function issetCheck($post, $key) {
    if (isset($post[$key])) {
        $return = $post[$key];
    } else {
        $return = '';
    }
    return $return;
}


 public function insert_data(){

     $post = $_REQUEST;    

    $item_name= $this->issetCheck($post, 'item_name');         
    $amount = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_gross');
    $currency = $this->issetCheck($post, 'mc_currency');
    $payer_email = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_email');
    $first_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'first_name');
    $last_name = $this->issetCheck($post, 'last_name');
    $country = $this->issetCheck($post, 'residence_country');
    $txn_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_id');
    $txn_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'txn_type');
    $payment_status = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_status');
    $payment_type = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payment_type');
    $payer_id = $this->issetCheck($post, 'payer_id');
    $create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $payment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $paypal_sql = "INSERT INTO ipn_data_tbl (item_name,payer_email,first_name,last_name,amount,currency,country,txn_id,txn_type,payer_id,payment_status,payment_type,create_date,payment_date)
    VALUES ($item_name,'$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$amount','$currency','$country','$txn_id','$txn_type','$payer_id','$payment_status','$payment_type','$create_date','$payment_date')";
    mysql_query($paypal_sql); 

}
?>
```

Comment: its been a while since I played with Paypal but did you define a callback URL within Paypal?

Comment: "the script below does not work" and "when the below script runs, here is the error it gets at runtime or when communicating with PayPal" are two different types of information.  The latter seems to be missing from your question.

@PHPology, this solution is a caller, it does not use a callback URL

Comment: dear PHPology I did not define a return URL. it is not mentioned in the explanations of PAYPAL.

Comment: Preston PHX when I write that it does not work I mean that it does not pass anything and I have no error displayed even in the console.

Comment: hello, I set up callback URL and of course used the PAYPAL script. I went to the history of IPN messages and I have an HTTP 500 error. I think there may be a syntax error in the PAYPAL script they are specialists in this kind of error.

Comment: i found one error on the last script, I remove 'public' just before 'function insert_data()' and when I went to the history of IPN messages and I have an HTTP 200 so is correct. but no work and I don't now where is a problem

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. Paypal provides scripts that do not work because there are syntax errors. Their explanation of the methods is very obscure. Finally after making some syntax and url modification my php IPN paypal IPN listener software works.

```js
<?php

$charset = "utf-8";

include('../config/dbconn.php');
 $deb='je commence';
 mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$deb')");

/* NE RIEN MODIFIER CI-DESSOUS */

// lecture du post de PayPal et ajout de 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = trim(urlencode(stripslashes($value)));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

//mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$req')");

// reponse a PayPal pour validation
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
//$header .= "Content-Length: 1028\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
//$header .= "Host: ipnpb.paypal.com:443\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//$fp = fsockopen ('ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('fp1')");
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$fp')");

// variables
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$insurance_amount = $_POST['insurance_amount'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$address_country_code = $_POST['address_country_code'];
$ipn_track_id = $_POST['ipn_track_id'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$charset = $_POST['charset'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$shipping_discount = $_POST['shipping_discount'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$test_ipn = $_POST['test_ipn'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$transaction_subject = $_POST['transaction_subject'];
$shipping_method = $_POST['shipping_method'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$protection_eligibility = $_POST['protection_eligibility'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$address_name = $_POST['address_name'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$residence_country = $_POST['residence_country'];

$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];


mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$txn_id')");
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('Date')");
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$payment_date')");
$rest = substr($payment_date, 9, 13);
$mois = substr($rest, 0, 3);
$jour = substr($rest, 4, 2);
$an = substr($rest, 8, 4);
$date = $an.'-'.$mois.'-'.$jour;
$date = date_create($date);
$dte = date_format($date,'Y-m-d');

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
fseek($fp, 0);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 10024);
//$test=strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED");
//if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
$deba = 'verifie';
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$deba')");
// Envoi du mail
   
  $paypal_sql = "INSERT INTO paiements (payment_id,payment_status,payment_amount,taxe_paypal,payment_currency,payment_date,payer_email)
    VALUES ('$txn_id','$payment_status','$mc_gross','$mc_fee','$mc_currency','$dte','$payer_email')";
    mysqli_query($dbconn,$paypal_sql); 


}
else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0) {
$debb = 'invalide';
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$debb')");

 $payment_status = 'INVALID';
  $paypal_sql = "INSERT INTO paiements (payment_id,payment_status,payment_amount,taxe_paypal,payment_currency,payment_date,payer_email)
    VALUES ('$txn_id','$payment_status','$mc_gross','$mc_fee','$mc_currency','$dte','$payer_email')";
    mysqli_query($dbconn,$paypal_sql); 


}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
$debc = 'fini';
mysqli_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO paytest (mess) VALUES ('$debc')");
?>
```